# Entity Framework - TPH - Derived entities with foreign key properties

Tags: entity-framework

If one or more of the sub-classes that reside in my TPH table have foreign key properties (i.e. class properties) how do I satisfy those constraints in EF after creating the derived entities and moving the derived-specific properties to the derived classes?